# Swift collectionview choose to not return a cell at cellForItemAt

Tags: swift, hide, collectionview

I've been struggling with the problem that when I do not want a cell to be displayed at the function cellForRowAt.

I tries to hide the cell but it gives me a white space between other cells.

I want to check before displaying the cell if a value exists in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your original array with existing value element and return its count also configure your cell from the copied array.

Answer (score 0):

why do not you use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout _: UICollectionViewLayout!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath _: IndexPath!) -> CGSize {
    if !exists {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}
```

you can customise any `collectionViewCell` size